# zsh zstyle file-patterns not matching dot properly

Tags: zsh

I'm having an issue with file-patterns on zstyle:

% zstyle ':completion:*:*:yes:files' file-patterns '*XXX.*'

(using "yes" as just an example)

Now when I do "yes XXX", I get:

% yes XXX
XXX-YYY.4  XXX.3

Why is it giving me XXX-YYY.4 as an option when it does't match the file-patterns, in that it doesn't have a dot after the XXX?

Answer (score 0):

The tag `files` includes any file, specifying an additional `file-patterns` does not subtract non matching files.

Following the example for `file-patterns` from `man 1 zshcompsys`, just replace `files` by `*`

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:yes:*' file-patterns '*XXX.*'
```

Now only file with names matching `*XXX.*` will be offered.